# Convex optimization: if $x \in cl(A)$, then $x \in A + \mathbb{B}_{\epsilon}(0) \cap aff(A).$

Tags: general-topology, convex-optimization

I found this statement in these lecture notes: [https://www1.se.cuhk.edu.hk/~manchoso/2021/engg5501/2-cvxanal.pdf](https://www1.se.cuhk.edu.hk/%7Emanchoso/2021/engg5501/2-cvxanal.pdf). It is in the proof of Prop. 7, page 9.

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}.$ $aff(A)$ is as defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_hull. $cl(A)$ is not explicitly defined in the notes, but it is the closure of A wrt to its affine hull, so $cl(A) = \{ x \in aff(A): \forall \epsilon >0, \mathbb{B}_{\epsilon}(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset \}. $

Here $\mathbb{B}_{\epsilon}(x)$ denotes the Euclidean ball around an element $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}. $

**The statement that I want to prove or refute from the notes is:**

**"Let $\epsilon >0.$ If $x \in cl(A)$, then $x \in A + \mathbb{B}_{\epsilon}(0) \cap aff(A).$"**

My reasoning: Suppose $x \in cl(A)$ and $\epsilon >0.$ There is $a \in \mathbb{B}_{\epsilon}(x),$ so that $x - a \in \mathbb{B}_{\epsilon}(0)$ and $x = a + x-a \in A + \mathbb{B}_{\epsilon}(0).$ However, by definition of $cl(A),$ $x \in aff(A),$ so $x \in ( A + \mathbb{B}_{\epsilon}(0) ) \cap aff(A).$ So, $x = a + y$ with $y \in \mathbb{B}_{\epsilon}(0)$ and $a = \sum_{i = 1}^{k} \lambda_{i}x_{i}$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lambda_{i} \in \mathbb{R}, i \in \{ 1, .., k\}$ and $\sum_{i = 1}^{k}\lambda_{i} = 1.$ So, if we write $y = x - a,$ $y$ is a weighted sum of elements of $A,$ whose weights sum to $0$ instead of $1,$ so it can't be in the affine hull of A.

Can someone find my mistake and explain why the statement holds, in case it does?

Comment: I think you should write the statement that you want to prove explicitly in the body of your question. It's kind of stated in the title, but the statement in the title doesn't introduce $\epsilon$. Is the conclusion supposed to be "then $x \in (A + B_\epsilon(0)) \cap \text{aff}(A)$ for all $\epsilon > 0$"?

Comment: @littleO Thank you for the advice! I've adjusted the the body like you suggested. Yes, I choose an arbitrary $\epsilon>0,$ so it should hold for all $\epsilon >0.$